# Making a tall, right-pointing triangle be the right side of a div

Tags: css

Part of a mockup I'm working on is the following.

[image]

I'm trying to get the triangular right end of the "Delay Your Payments" `div` to match the mockup, if possible using CSS without using any sliced images and without using using any absolutely valued pixels or anything that will screw up if the dimensions of the container change after more text is added.

Attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/a7L3tytp/

HTML:

```
<div class="delay-your-payments">
    <h3>Delay Your Payments</h3>
    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.delay-your-payments { background: #1AA3B4; padding: 20px; position: relative; width: 80%; }
div.delay-your-payments:after { color: #1AA3B4; right: 0; position: absolute; content: "\25B6"; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); right: -11px; }
    div.delay-your-payments > h3 { color: #FFF; }
    div.delay-your-payments > p { color: #FFF; }
```

Comment: this might help:http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: @BrianGlaz can that be used to make the height equal to the height of the containing div?

Comment: probably not, unless you already know the height of the containing div. of course you could aways use javascript on page load to get / set it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution

```css
div.delay-your-payments { float:left;background: #1AA3B4; padding: 20px; height:200px;position: relative; width: 80%; }
    div.delay-your-payments > h3 { color: #FFF; }
    div.delay-your-payments > p { color: #FFF; }

.arrow-right {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 100px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
 border-left: 100px solid green;
    float:left;
}
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="delay-your-payments">
    <h3>Delay Your Payments</h3>
    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```